# smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'5.7.1 This message is not RFC 5322 compliant. There are multiple To headers

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am getting an error saying that there are multiple "To" headers when trying to automate my emailing program to send an image to multiple recipients. The email seems to only be sent to the first email in the receiver_emails list.

Here is what I have as my code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

port = 465  # For SSL
app_pass = "my_app_password"
sender_email = "Sender@gmail.com"
receiver_emails = ["example1@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com"]

# Email details
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Email Subject Line"
message["From"] = sender_email

# EMAIL BODY
# Create the plain-text and HTML version of your message
text = """\
"""
html = """\
<html>
<body>
    <img src="cid:image1">
</body>
</html>
"""

# OPENING THE IMAGE
fp = open('MotivationalQuote.jpeg', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
# Define the image's ID as referenced above
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')

# Turn these into plain/html MIMEText objects
part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

# Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
# The email client will try to render the last part first
message.attach(msgImage)
message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)

# Sending an email to each recipient within email list

for email in receiver_emails:
    message["To"] = email
    # Create a secure SSL context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, app_pass)
        # TODO: Send email here
        # Iterate through recipients
        server.sendmail(sender_email, email, message.as_string())
```

for the last part, the for loop, I also tried doing it this way and still got the same error message:

```
# Sending an email to each recipient within email list

message["To"] = email
# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, app_pass)
    # TODO: Send email here
    # Iterate through recipients
    for email in receiver_emails:
        server.sendmail(sender_email, email, message.as_string())
```

Comment: Like the error message suggests, make a single `To:` header with all the recipients, comma-separated (or maybe use `Bcc:`)

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: @tripleee Thanks alot! i was able to figure it out thanks to the resource you provided!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @tripleee for the resource he provided; I was able to figure it out thanks to him. Apparently, I had been using an outdated library, which led to many complications. I instead went for the EmailMessage library, and it works flawlessly. Here's the updated code:

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.utils import make_msgid

port = 465  # For SSL
app_pass = "my_app_pass"
sender_email = "myemail@gmail.com"
receiver_emails = ["example1@gmail.com", "example2@gmail.com"]

for email in receiver_emails:
    # Create the base text message.
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = "Subject Line"
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = email
    msg.set_content("""\
    Alternative content
    """)

    # Add the html version.  This converts the message into a multipart/alternative
    # container, with the original text message as the first part and the new html
    # message as the second part.
    quote_cid = make_msgid()
    msg.add_alternative("""\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>Today's Motivational Quote:</p>
        <br/>
        <img src="cid:{quote_cid}" />
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(quote_cid=quote_cid[1:-1]), subtype='html')
    # note that we needed to peel the <> off the msgid for use in the html.

    # Now add the related image to the html part.
    with open("MotivationalQuote.png", 'rb') as img:
        msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'jpeg',
                                        cid=quote_cid)

    # Send the message via SMTP server.
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
        server.login(sender_email, app_pass)
        # Send email here
        server.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: It's still borderline abusive to send the same message again and again. Send it once to all the recipients if you don't crucially require each message to be different.

Comment: (Also, the `text/plain` content should be the actual message in plain text, not some crummy placeholder which effectively communicates "we hate you for not preferring HTML".)

Comment: Now that you mention it, it makes much more sense lol. I’ll try not to accidentally discriminate against people who don’t prefer HTML, haha. Thanks for your help!